# Is there any way, i Want to change the build no. when ng build is executed in angular 8?

Tags: angular8

I am new to angular 8.I am not sure if there is a way in angular.
I want to change the build no. and build date when i run ng build command.
Currently i am changing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change the build no?

If you want just a static name for your build you can use `ng build --outputHashing none`.
this will generate built files with the same name